# Multiple Cycle on Code First Approach Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

```
public class Admission
{
    [Required]
    public int AdmissionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SscInformationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int HscInformationId { get; set; }

    public SscInformation SscInformation { get; set; }

    public HscInformation HscInformation { get; set; }
 }

public class HscInformation
{
    [Required]
    public int HscInformationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EducationBoardId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RollNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PassingYear { get; set; }

    public EducationBoard EducationBoard { get; set; }
}

public class SscInformation
{
    [Required]
    public int SscInformationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EducationBoardId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RollNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PassingYear { get; set; }

    public EducationBoard EducationBoard { get; set; }
}

public class EducationBoard
{
    [Required]
    public int EducationBoardId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Education Board Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Education Board Name")]
    public string EducationBoardName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Data Model. When i try to create database using code first approach in entity framework, It gives me following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.SscInformations_dbo.EducationBoards_EducationBoardId' on table 'SscInformations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How can i solve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `SscInformation` and `SscInformation` have a required `EducationBoard` (because `EducationBoardId` is required). That means that these associations have cascaded delete enabled by default.

So suppose you have an `EducationBoard` that is referred to by a `SscInformation` *and* a `SscInformation`. If you delete this `EducationBoard`, cascading delete would also want to delete these referring objects. This is a *multiple cascade path*.

It's a Sql Server restriction not to allow multiple (or circular) cascade paths, so a `SqlException` occurs while EF tries to build the database.

You have to make at least one of the associations non cascading, e.g.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SscInformation>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.EducationBoard).WithRequiredDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

(in the context's `OnModelCreating` override.)

Comment: Thanks @Gert Arnold. It works. But it makes one to many relationship between 'SscInformation' and 'EducationBoard'. I want to make one to one relationship between this. Is there any way to to this ??